# Protractors browser.actions() to simulate drag & drop does not work

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, typescript, angular, protractor

I use Protractor to test angular2 app.

I use browser.actions() to simulate drag and drop in such a way:

```
let dragElement = element.all(by.className('layer')).get(0).getWebElement();
let dropElement = element.all(by.className('layer')).get(1).getWebElement();
browser.actions()
.mouseDown(dragElement)
.mouseMove(dropElement)
.mouseUp()
.perform();
```

The action of drag and drop is not happening. I know the elements are found, because when executing:

```
browser.actions().mouseDown(dragElement).perform()
```

I can see that the mouse button is pressed on the control.

Node Version: 5.10.1
Protractor Version: 3.3.0
Browser(s): chrome
Operating System and Version windows 7 x64

Comment: Have you tried the `browser.actions().dragAndDrop(dragElement, dropElement).perform()`?

Comment: Yep, I have tried this also in the first place. Does not work either.